# How to filter and list data from another sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some help for my Excel formula. I am trying to select specific rows based on the values in those rows.

Let's say these are my values:

```
╔══════════╦═════════╦══════╗
║   Data   ║  Month  ║ Name ║
╠══════════╬═════════╬══════╣
║ Value 1  ║ january ║ mark ║
║ Value 2  ║ january ║ mark ║
║ Value 3  ║ january ║ rick ║
║ Value 4  ║ january ║ rick ║
║ Value 5  ║ march   ║ mark ║
║ Value 6  ║ march   ║ mark ║
║ Value 7  ║ march   ║ rick ║
║ Value 8  ║ march   ║ rick ║
║ Value 9  ║ august  ║ mark ║
║ Value 10 ║ august  ║ rick ║
╚══════════╩═════════╩══════╝
```

The value in A1 = january
The value in A2 = mark

I want to list all the rows where the month is A1 and the name is A2.
This should be my result:

```
║ Value 1  ║ january ║ mark ║
║ Value 2  ║ january ║ mark ║
```

I have tried using INDEX combined with IF, but with no succes. I am looking for either a VBA solution or a formula, whatever is best.

Comment: A pivot table should be able to handle what you want to do.

Comment: Filtering, then selecting is the basic function you want.  If you need to automate that, then you are headed to VBA land.  Best starting point, use the Macro Recorder and perform the steps manually. That will get you 90% of the way there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that:

1. 'Data' is in Sheet1!A1, 'Month' is in Sheet1!B1 and 'Name' is in Sheet1!C1.
2. On Sheet2!A1 is the value of 'Month' which you want to filter out and on Sheet2!A1 is the value of 'Name' you want to filter out.

Make a new column in Sheet1!D1 (beside 'Name') and give it a header, eg. 'Tag'. In the first row, D1 (under 'Tag') write the formula

---

**=IF(AND(B2=Sheet2!$A$1,C2=Sheet2!$A$2),MAX($D$1:D1)+1,"")**

---

Pull (copy) the above formula down till the last row of your table.

On Sheet2, replicate your table headers, this time in B1, C1 and D1 (as A1 & A2 already have your filter values).

// now everything is for Sheet2

In B2 write the following formula:

---

**=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(ROWS($B$2:B2),Sheet1!$D:$D,0)),"")**

---

Paste this formula in the new filter table rows.

Change values in Sheet2!A1 (Month) and Sheet2!A2 (Name) to test if the correct rows are being filtered.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer helped me achieve exactly what I wanted! Just one thing: I think the second "Sheet2!A1" under bullet 2. should be "Sheet2!A2" and the first formula should be copied in D2 and not D1. ;)